# how to replace html form hidden fields values with external values in android.?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have html form .which is store in assets folder as index.html file.I am display this form in web view.This html form contains some hidden fields and I want to replace these values with my values .Which is get from Intent .I don't understand how to get hidden field from web view and replace with my values.Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
```

```
</head>
<body>
<table width="50%" align="center">
<TR><TD colspan="2"><span class="style1">Post comments</span></TD>
</TR>
<form  action="http://www.indianexpress.com/ajax/saveComment.php" id="frmcommentmain" name="frmcommentmain" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="918703" name="storyId">
<input type="hidden" value="172.16.24.10" name="ip_addr">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="parentcmtId">

<TR><TD height="35">Name:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="name" tiptitle="Please enter your name" size="15">
  *</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Email:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="email"  tiptitle="Please enter your email" size="15">
  *</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Title:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="subject" tiptitle="Please enter subject" size="15">
  *</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Comment:</TD><TD><textarea title="Please enter your comments"  rows="6" name="comment"></textarea>
  *</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="checkbox">I agree to the terms of use.</TD></TR>
<TR>
  <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD colspan="2"><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit"></TD></TR>
</form>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to replace story_id and ip_addr values.

Answer (score 0):

Call `loadUrl("javascript:...")` on your `WebView` after loading this page, where the `...` is replaced by JavaScript code to fill in the values you wish.